# How to properly include a custom hosts file while building AOSP from source?

Tags: android, build, android-source

I am building a custom ROM from AOSP. I have collected a hosts file that can block ads and malware. I want to include this hosts file during AOSP build so that it is integrated into the ROM and users do not need root apps to block ads. What is the best method to include the following hosts file during AOSP build?

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this file : {AOSP Dir}/system/core/rootdir/etc/hosts

https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/rootdir/etc/hosts